# IPSec Policy Is Blocking 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, vpn, pptp, ipsec, loopback

I created an IPSec policy on Windows 8.1, it's purpose was to allow only traffic that goes via the VPN, everything else should be blocked (except LAN and 127.0.0.1). LAN is working fine, but 127.0.0.1 is not, this causes a lot of programs not to work.

I will attempt to explain everything, but if you know what you're doing then you can [**download my policy here**](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zsiu72g3gqvezqy/IPSec.zip).

The below screenshot shows the basic outline of my policy...

[image: IPSec Policy]

- **All Traffic** -- Blocks all traffic on all ports and all IPs
- **LAN Traffic** -- Allows traffic across the network (192.168.0.0/16)
- **VPN PPTP Connections** -- Allows TCP port 1723 and protocol 47 for VPN connections
- **VPN Traffic** -- Allows all traffic between 10.0.0.0/8 and any other IP

---

The above works except that now 127.0.0.1 is not accessible.

Some programs, for example TOR & VMWare, will open a port on 127.0.0.1, as per the screenshot below...

[image: Resource Monitor]

---

My goal is to force all remote traffic through the VPN, while still having access to 127.0.0.1.

- How can I achieve this?
- Will modifying my policy fix the problem?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound - I would like to have my programs working, one way or another. If 127.0.0.1 can be allowed some how, then I think this would fix it. I will edit the question.